# How to create a variable in Shiny app and use it to plot

Tags: r, shiny

If I have a tibble df3 of three columns (a,b,c) outside the ui and server. I want to have the option to select ,a,b,c or d, where d is a new tibble made in the server from df3. Why do I get an error when I select d?

```
df3 <- tibble("rand"=rep(1:3, times = 10),
            "a"= rnorm(30),
             "b" = rgamma(30, 1,2),
             "c"= rpois(30,5))


ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                  selectizeInput("selection", "Select a letter",
                              choices = c("A"="a","B"="b","C"="c","D"="d"))
                  
            
            ),
            mainPanel(
                  plotOutput("plot"),
                  tableOutput("table")
            )
            
      )
)

server <- function(input, output){
      reactive_df<- reactive({
            if(input$selection == "D"){
                  df3 %>% group_by(rand) %>% 
                        summarise(d = mean(a))
            }else{df3}
      })
      output$table <- renderTable({
            reactive_df()
      })
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
      
            ggplot(reactive_df())+
            aes_string("rand", input$selection)+
            geom_point()
      })
```

I've tried the code outside of shiny and it works fine. I can see the data and the plot. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write `"D" = "d"` in `choices` in the `selectizeInput`, the variable is internally stored as `"d"`. So the `if`-clause in the `reactive` should be `if(input$selection == "d")`. Otherwise you get the error message `object 'd' not found`.